# knockout.js - add/remove items from child list of model

Tags: model-view-controller, foreach, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a foreach template displaying a list of jobs on a page.  Inside each job I have a list of job notes.  I'm having trouble setting up the proper observable to allow for the job notes to be updated in the view.

Here is a link to a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3B8p/

Or, here is the code as it stands.  I'm not sure whether to put the observable array of the sublist into the Job object itself or into the View...

```
<div data-bind="foreach: jobs">
    <div>
        <div class="jobContainer">
            <label data-bind="text: JobTitle"></label> 
            <label data-bind="text: CompanyName"></label>
            <div class="jobDetails" data-bind="visible: expanded">
                <label data-bind="text: City"></label>
                <label data-bind="text: State"></label>
                <div data-bind="foreach: Notes">
                    <label data-bind="text: Text"></label>               
                </div> 
            </div>                           
        <div>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.toggle, text: linkLabel">Expand</a> 
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.addNote">Add Note</a>  
    </div>    
</div>    


function JobNote() {
    this.Text = "some text!";       
}

function Job() {
    this.JobTitle = ko.observable("some job");
    this.CompanyName = ko.observable("some company");
    this.City = ko.observable("some city");
    this.State = ko.observable("some state");
    this.Notes = ko.observableArray([
       new JobNote(),
       new JobNote(),       
    ]);

    this.someValue = ko.observable().extend({ defaultIfNull: "some default" });

    this.expanded = ko.observable(false);

    this.linkLabel = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.expanded() ? "collapse" : "expand";
    }, this);      
};

var viewModel = function () {
    this.jobs= ko.observableArray([
        new Job(),
        new Job(),
        new Job(),
        new Job(),
        new Job(),
        new Job(),
        new Job(),
        new Job(),
        new Job(),        
        new Job(),
    ]);

    this.toggle = function (item) {
        item.expanded(!item.expanded());
    }

    this.addNote = function(job) {
         // what should go in here?
    }    
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());​
```

Comment: I'd put `addNote()` into "Job" since the observable you're modifying is a part of "Job".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Niko said in this scenario I would add the method to the class. Like so.

```
function Job() {
    var self = this;

    this.JobTitle = ko.observable("some job");
    this.CompanyName = ko.observable("some company");
    this.City = ko.observable("some city");
    this.State = ko.observable("some state");

    this.Notes = ko.observableArray([
       new JobNote(),
       new JobNote(),       
    ]);

    this.someValue = ko.observable().extend({ defaultIfNull: "some default" });

    this.expanded = ko.observable(false);

    this.linkLabel = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.expanded() ? "collapse" : "expand";
    }, this);   

    this.toggle = function () {
        self.expanded(!self.expanded());
    };

    this.addNote = function () {
        self.Notes.push(new JobNote());
    }    
};
```

This keeps everything nice and encapsulated.

Hope this helps.